# apt sources.list ssh://[REMOTE REPO URL] getting connection timeout

Tags: ssh, debian, apt

We have created custom package repository for our edge device on the remote server.

We have specified the url in sources.list as below

[sources.list file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvRBA.png)

This link was working fine earlier and we were able to get the new packages using this link.
Suddenly this link is not working fine and we are getting "Connection timed out" when we ran the "apt-get update" command as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAAUy.png)

Any one using custom debain package repository faced similar issue earlier.
I am unable to find any information which can cause this issue.

Comment: A timeout usually indicates a firewall issue

Comment: @GeraldSchneider We are able to connect and download packages from test package repository. But for production package repository, we are getting timeout issue.